# TurboRepo starts webserver and then immediately successfully exists

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, pnpm, turborepo

I have turborepo set up with pnpm and I'm trying to start the react frontend of one of my clients with this command:
`npx turbo run start --filter=testclient`

Here's the output from this command:

```
• Packages in scope: testclient
• Running start in 1 packages
testclient:start: cache bypass, force executing 4ef91202eb77e2b8
testclient:start: 
testclient:start: > testclient@0.0.1 start /Users/me/frontend/frontend-core/clients/testclient
testclient:start: > node node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js --max-old-space-size=4096 start
testclient:start: 
testclient:start: ℹ ｢wds｣: Project is running at http://192.168.0.54/
testclient:start: ℹ ｢wds｣: webpack output is served from 
testclient:start: ℹ ｢wds｣: Content not from webpack is served from /Users/me/frontend/frontend-core/clients/testclient/public
testclient:start: ℹ ｢wds｣: 404s will fallback to /
testclient:start: Starting the development server...
testclient:start: 

 Tasks:    1 successful, 1 total
Cached:    0 cached, 1 total
  Time:    2.339s
```

As you can see, turbo starts the development server without issues, but then it immediately exists instead of keeping the server running.

In my `/turbo.json`, I have `start` specified here:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://turborepo.org/schema.json",
  "pipeline": {
    "start": { "cache": false },
    ...
```

`/pnpm-workspace.yaml`:

```
packages:
  - 'packages/*'
  - 'clients/**'
  - '!**/tests/**'
```

`/package.json`:

```
{
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "clients/*",
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    [ no "start" script here as only packages in '/clients' have that ]
    ...
```

`/clients/testclient/package.json` containing the "start" script:

```
{
  "name": "testclient",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js --max-old-space-size=4096 start",
    ...
```

I'm able to get turborepo to build without issues by running `npx turbo run build --filter=testclient`

Curiously, I am able to start the dev server by running `npm start --prefix=clients/testclient`, but the output looks different:

```
Compiled with warnings.

/Users/me/frontend/frontend-core/packages/frontend-core/dist/frontend-core.css (/Users/me/frontend/frontend-core/node_modules/.pnpm/css-loader@3.4.2_webpack@4.42.0/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!/Users/me/frontend/frontend-core/node_modules/.pnpm/postcss-loader@3.0.0/node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!/Users/me/frontend/frontend-core/packages/frontend-core/dist/frontend-core.css)
Warning

(14:63200) end value has mixed support, consider using flex-end instead

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

Any idea why turborepo just exists as soon as the server starts, taking the server down with it?

Answer (score 1):

One possible explanation is that the server is actually crashing on launch.
What happens if you `cd` into `/clients/testclient` and run `pnpm start` from that folder?

---

You may also try adding `persistent: true` to your `start` pipeline (although [according to the docs](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/reference/configuration#persistent), this shouldn't have any effect)